# How can I insert a text (string) into an ion-textarea?

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've already tried this:

example.html:

```
<ion-textarea placeholder="Enter your thoughts" type="text">Test: {{ textboxContent }} </ion-textarea>
```

The string `textboxContent` is filled with `"Test"`.

There is nothing in the textarea. Except for the placeholder, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ngModel to achieve this

```
<ion-textarea placeholder="Enter your thoughts" type="text" [(ngModel)]="value">Test: {{ textboxContent }} </ion-textarea>
```

and in your **component.ts**,

```
export class Page{
value:string;
  constructor(){
    this.value="some value you want to fill"
  }
}
```